# VBA Error 1004 Application Definition Error or Object Definition

Tags: excel, vba

I would get help if possible.
I have two worksheets in the same workbook. Through a form, I search the "Dados" worksheet and copy the result to the "Pesquisa" worksheet. The results are shown in a listview. When I double click on a result, it occurs: **"Error 1004 Application definition error or object definition"**. I do not understand the reason for the error, since I've already reviewed my code and found no problems.

Thank you very much for your help. Below, follow my code.

```
    Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)  
      Sheets("Dados").Range("A" & Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2)).Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you add a control expression for the (ListBox1.ListIndex + 2), what number do you get?

Comment: You are calling the range incorrectly I believe. If I assume `ListBox1.ListIndex + 2` is a number, currently it resolves to `Range("A" & "W2")` which isn't correct. You need something like `...Range("A1:"& ...)`

Comment: As a guess, I'd say the reference to `Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2)` is not returning a valid number. I'd recommend breaking out those nested references into intermediate variables to make clear what you're trying to access, so you can check values along the way.

Comment: Wait - You're calling the range on `Dados` sheet, but also trying to `Select` a range from another.  I believe that's a reason it's failing as well.

Comment: @Ass3mbler, in this case, I get number 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Sheets("Dados").Range("A" & Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2)).Select
> ```

That's a lot of things going on in a single statement, with *several* reasons for things to go awry.

Break it down.

First get your `Worksheet` objects:

```
Dim dadosSheet As Worksheet
Set dadosSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dados") 'possible error 9 here

Dim pesquisaSheet As Worksheet
Set pesquisaSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pesquisa") 'possible error 9 here
```

Next we want to build a `Range` address string in column `W`, from `ListBox1.ListIndex`, and get a `rowIndex` from that cell in the `pesquisaSheet`:

```
Dim rowSourceAddress As String
rowSourceAddress = "W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2 ' definitely a positive integer

Dim rowIndex As Long
rowIndex = pesquisaSheet.Range(rowSourceAddress).Value ' possible error 13 here
Debug.Assert rowIndex > 0 ' suspect this assertion will fail
```

Then we want to build another `Range` address string in column `A`:

```
Dim targetAddress As String
targetAddress = "A" & rowIndex ' if rowIndex isn't a positive integer...

Dim targetRange As Range
Set targetRange = dadosSheet.Range(targetAddress) '...error 1004 is thrown here
```

And lastly we want to `Select` that range:

```
targetRange.Select
```

Sure, it's more code - and arguably a bit more local variables than needed. But with everything explicit and every member call in its own instruction, any given instruction has only 1 reason to fail, which makes debugging much easier.

Comment: alright alright alright *matthew mcconaughey voice*

Comment: `Dim targetRange As Range
Set targetRange = dadosSheet.Range(targetAddress)`

Yes, the error actually thrown here, with the following message: Run-time error 1004: The Range method of the _Worksheet object failed.

Comment: @user2734504 so now you only need to look at the value of `sourceRowAddress` in the actual worksheet to find where the worksheet contains bad data =)

Comment: Ok, @MathieuGuindon! `rowSourceAddress` retuns the W2. But, there is no data in this cell.

Comment: @user2734504 and that empty cell makes `targetAddress` be `A0`, which is why error 1004 is thrown :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, Right! If I set a value in W2, the error does not occur. However, when I double click on the results of the listview, the value of A & (W2 value) is highlighted. The correct one would be to highlight the value of A corresponding to the line on which the result is. For example: If W2 is equal to 1, double click always highlights cell A1 even if my registration is referring to line 2 or line 3 or line 5 and so on ...

Comment: @user2734504 looks like you're on track!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon,  the solution found, based on your instructions, was to put the value of W2 equal to the index's value that interested me in a While Loop. The expression that was placed inside the loop was:
`Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("H" & n).Offset(1, 15).Value = ActiveCell.Row`

So, it works fine!
Thank you! =)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you may need to include `.Value` in your expression.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)  
    Sheets("Dados").Range("A" & Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2).Value).Select
End Sub
```

Additionally, are you confident that the value at `Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2).Value` is a **positive integer**? If not, this will throw that error you are receiving.

Comment: Indeed, that's the one reason error 1004 could be thrown - have an upvote! =)

Comment: Yes, it's an integer value (use as a sequential code to identify the people registered in the Dados Worksheet). 
But the error still occurs even after inserting .Value. =(

Comment: @user2734504 `.Value` was implicit, making it explicit makes no real difference (other than enhancing the readability). Try breaking down the expression as suggested in another answer; there's an assertion that will definitely fail.

Comment: Couple of thoughts, first try `MsgBox Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2).Value` and see what value you get. Second, you might need a `Worksheet` reference before the `Listbox1`, so for example: `Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & Sheets("Pesquisa").ListBox1.ListIndex + 2).Value`. Third, I know sometimes directly referring to Comboboxes doesn't work for me so I have to do something along the lines of: `Sheets("Pesquisa").OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.ListIndex`, might not be needed in your case but wanted to give an fyi

Comment: But yea definitely look at @MathieuGuindon 's answer and you can really narrow down why the error is happening

Comment: The `ListBox1` doesn't strike me as a problem though; the code seems to be in a handler for that very listbox control, so its location makes no difference: if it's a UserForm, then it's implicitly `Me.ListBox1`; if it's a Worksheet, then it's still implicitly `Me.ListBox1` - qualifying it with anything other than `Me` makes it a roundabout reference IMO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox "You selected:" & vbCrLf & ListBox1.ListIndex & ": " & ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
    'Sheets("Dados").Range("A" & Sheets("Pesquisa").Range("W" & ListBox1.ListIndex + 2)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, the msgbox shows: 'You selected: 0:2'.

Comment: This means that "Entry0" from Listbox1 was selected. The value of this entry is "2". Now you can continue according to the excellent answer from @Mathieu Guindon.